# how to merge video with PowerPoint file?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, merge

I want to merge video with PowerPoint file into a single video file -- related PowerPoint is displayed when the video is showed (like some online training experience), and I want to know whether there are any Microsoft tools (I have MSDN license so to save my money) or any free or 3rd party tools on Windows platform?

Answer (score 1):

use something like camtasia (other video capture products are available) to capture the powerpoint presentation to video, and then combine the two videos in your favourite video editing appliaction.