# Nice way to show Powerpoints and Video

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, mplayer

I'm looking for a sleek way to display Powerpoint presentations and video footage in sequence.
Embedding video in .ppsx is not something i want to do, reasons are plenty (video footage being VC-1 1080p would be the first).

Is there a media player (needs to run on win32) capable of playing both formats?

My hackish way of doing this would be a .cmd with

```
powerpnt.exe bobloblaw.ppsx
mplayer.exe -fs video.wmv
pwoerpnt.exe whitepowerbill.ppsx
and so on
```

Of course, this has a truckload of drawbacks, including begin really hard to break out of the chain :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the powerpoint into a video and then merge the 2 videos into a new single video ?

see [how to merge video with powerpoint file?](https://superuser.com/questions/47058/how-to-merge-video-with-powerpoint-file)

Answer (score 0):

Running external applications is built-in behavior of Powerpoint:

- Insert an action or right-click the shape, and select **Action Settings**.
- On the Mouse Click or Mouse Over tab, select **Run program**.
- Enter the **application name and command line switches** in the text box.

Haven't tried the next thing, but I guess you can automatize a slide showing a video by:

- Create **a black shape as big as the slide** and set it's **Mouse Over** to run the video.
- Configure it so that the slide automatically progresses to the next slide so that you see the next slide once the video is done. Worst case, you'll have to slightly move your mouse for the video to show.